# Should I keep Android Bluetooth Server Thread in Service or Application?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I want to keep the Bluetooth Server Thread alive as long as the Android Phone is on.
Should I manage the thread in Service or the Application?
Service, Application, Which one live longer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are referring to when you say Application. An Application can be comprised of one or more Services and/or one or more Activities. From your description, though, you want a background Service.

Edit:
As far as a `Service` getting shut down, that is always a possibility. If there are clients bound to your `Service`, it is highly unlikely that the OS will shut it down.

If you believe your `Service` **absolutely** needs to be running at all times (which is not likely given proper design), the only thing you can legitimately do is run it as a foreground `Service`. Even then it may be shut down under ["extreme memory pressure"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) (see Process Lifecycle).

Comment: The Application I am saying is the tag <application> in the androidmanifest.xml. Would the background Service shutdown by the system when the memory is low?

Comment: You mean that the life cycle of Application won't be finished until all the Services and Activities belong to it finished?

Comment: [Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html) don't have their own lifecycle, per se. In that link, look under Application Components. See my edit about `Service`s being killed.

Comment: Thanks, Dave! I think I need to rebuild my code~